# How can I find the largest slope value in a list of coordinates?

Tags: arrays, perl

I am trying to figure out how to determine the maximum/highest slope value when I have data in the format below. I have this data stored in an array. The first two columns are X and Y coordinates, respectively. I basically want to plug in every possible pair from this data into the slope formula and determine the highest possible value.

Data Format:

```
6.3 -7.2
-5.6 -2.4
2.1 7.8
5.2 1.4
```

So far I have:

```
sub maxSlope {
my @data; #Contains all the values
foreach $line (@data){
  @split_data = split(' ', $line);
  my ($x1, $y1) = ($split_data[0], $[split_data[1]);
  }

  #$my_slope = ($y2-$y1)/($x2-$x1); 
}
```

So far I am only able to get the first pair in two variables. I am having difficulty figuring out how I can get the next pair in two variables `($x2, $y2)` and compute via the slope formula `(y2-y1/x2-x1)` for every possible pair given the data set. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: `for $i(0..$#data){ ($x1,$y1) = split(" " ,$data[$i]); ($x2,$y2) = split(" ",$data[$i+1]); }`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I keep running into these errors using this solution. It appears that all coordinates are being stored in $x1 only for some reason. Use of uninitialized value $y1 in concatenation (.) or string at ./slope.pl line 47, <STDIN> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $x2 in concatenation (.) or string at ./slope.pl line 47, <STDIN> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $y2 in concatenation (.) or string at ./slope.pl line 47, <STDIN> line 1.

Comment: Actually this is not error this is warnings, try this `for $i(0..$#data-1)`

Comment: You may need to run it through `abs()` if you consider `-7` more *"slopey"* **TM** than `+5`.

Answer (score 0):

To use all pairs of points, for each point you need to loop over all others (but without duplication).

I've split the job into building the list of all slope-points first and then finding the top one, for flexibility so that you can more easily further experiment and adjust.  See comments below.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';    
#use Data::Dump qw(dd);

use List::Util qw(reduce);

my @data = ('6.3 -7.2', '-5.6 -2.4', '2.1 7.8', '5.2 1.4');

my $rslopes = get_slopes(\@data);    
#dd $rslopes;

my $top = reduce { ($a->[0] > $b->[0]) ? $a : $b } @$rslopes;

say "$top->[0]  for (@{$top->[1]}) and (@{$top->[2]})";

sub get_slopes {
    my @data = @{$_[0]};
    my @slopes;

    while (my $line = shift @data) {
        my ($x1, $y1) = split ' ', $line;
        for (@data) {
            my ($x2, $y2) = split;
            push @slopes, [ ($y2-$y1)/($x2-$x1), [$x1, $y1], [$x2, $y2] ];  
        }
    }   
    return \@slopes;
}
```

This prints the largest slope and its points, found using [List::Util::reduce](https://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#reduce).  Comments:

- Results are stored in an array with elements `[slope, [pt1], [pt2]]` since slopes *can* be equal within the precision so a hash `slope => [[pt1], [pt2]]` can't be used
- A value is `shift`ed from the array so that simply all remaining ones are then compared to it. Once the last one is removed there is an extra (unneeded) `split` and assignment
- Another way is with nested `for` loops, where the inner one iterates from `i+1` of the outer. Be careful with arranging the indices so it doesn't go past the post
- If you really only need that largest slope move the `reduce` line into the sub, rename the sub to `max_slope` (or such), and return the top slope's array `slope, [pt1], [pt2]` (or its ref). Or compare values as they are computed and you don't need `reduce`

To see them all (sorted), instead of just finding the largest one (with `reduce`) do

```
my @sorted_slopes = sort { $b->[0] <=> $a->[0] } @$rslopes; 

for (@sorted_slopes) {
    printf "%6.3f for (%4.1f %4.1f) and (%4.1f %4.1f)\n",  
        $_->[0], @{$_->[1]}, @{$_->[2]};
}
```

With this, the program above prints

```
 1.325 for (-5.6 -2.4) and ( 2.1  7.8)
 0.352 for (-5.6 -2.4) and ( 5.2  1.4)
-0.403 for ( 6.3 -7.2) and (-5.6 -2.4)
-2.065 for ( 2.1  7.8) and ( 5.2  1.4)
-3.571 for ( 6.3 -7.2) and ( 2.1  7.8)
-7.818 for ( 6.3 -7.2) and ( 5.2  1.4)
```